# Changing paths to directories in EE4

Tags: templates, ee4

Specifically the Templates directory and Add-ons. How do I do it? Doesn't seem to be working in the config file like in Version 2. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Sorry. It was a bit of an annoyance all around when I started upgrading clients from `EE2` to `EE3`. There is no config override for the `addons` (aka `third_party`) and no way to set the template folder path for sites.

Do you want to hack it? Well...

**DO NOT DO THIS**

In `/system/ee/legacy/libraries/Core.php`

`EE 3.5.16`: Line 76 and 78
`EE 4.3.0`: Line 63 and 65

```
    define('PATH_THIRD',  SYSPATH . 'user/addons/');
    ...
    define('PATH_TMPL',   SYSPATH . 'user/templates/');
```

Please don't edit that core file. Seriously, I just did some folder greping. There is a very low chance changing those lines will work, and even if they do, you've hacked the EE core. Literally, the worst practice in coding. It isn't broke. Don't try to fix it.

Seriously don't do this. Even if it does work, in the long run, you'll run into problems somewhere else because of it. I would quit working for you if you did, and fire you if you were my employee (/rant over, sorry for being dramatic :) ). The new folder structure is fine, you'll get used to it.

**Edit**

If you *really* have to, just set up your deployment system to use symlinks from those core folder to where you want to store them. Make sure you allow symlinks in your server architecture (Apache `Options FollowSymLinks` in vhosts, nginx ... somewhere, somehow. You'll have to Google it).

Comment: Thanks for this. Definitely don't want to mess around with the core files as this is intended to streamline things for versioning so less confusion the better. 

Wonder why they removed this functionality though. Will try the Symlinks - cheers!